# How to change the name of .lib when compiling a shared library with zig c++

Tags: c++, windows, zig

I'm currently trying to build a c++ project with zig c++.
If I build two files like this :

```bash
zig c++ -c src/math/Vector2.cpp -o ../bin/math/Vector2.o -Isrc
zig c++ -c src/collision/Manifold.cpp -o ../bin/collision/Manifold.o -Isrc
```

And then link them to a .dll with this command :

```bash
zig c++ -shared -o ../bin/test.dll ../bin/math/Vector2.o ..\bin\collision\Manifold.o
```

My bin folder will look like this :

- test.dll
- test.pdb
- Vector2.lib

And I really don't get the .lib is named Vector2 and how to rename it, is there anything i'm doing wrong ?

I found this issue that seems related https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/9210, but looking at the linked issues, i didn't find any solutions

when using -v, it's possible to see the command :

```
LLD Link... lld-link -ERRORLIMIT:0 -NOLOGO -DEBUG -PDB:../bin\test.pdb -PDBALTPATH:../bin\test.pdb -MACHINE:X64 -INCLUDE:_tls_index -DLL -OUT:../bin\test.dll -IMPLIB:../bin\Vector2.lib
```

Would be nice to just be able to modify the value of -IMPLIB

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the solution, I had to add this to the link command : `-Wl,--out-implib,../bin/stowy_physics_engine.lib`

This is because -Wl passes the next arguments to the linker, but this is quite platform specific.